# Undefined Response: Sending Message from Chrome App to Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to request a db from a chrome extension back to a chrome app. But the reply argument "response" logs as "undefined." Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

**Extension Background Script Snippet**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {

        console.log("RECIEVED REQUEST FROM APP");

        chrome.storage.local.get(lwsDatabaseName, function (storage) {

            if (lwsDatabaseName in storage) {

                console.log("SENDING THE DATABASE");
                console.log("SENDING: " + JSON.stringify(storage[lwsDatabaseName]));
                sendResponse({ data: storage[lwsDatabaseName] });

            } else {

                console.log("SENDING MESSAGE BACK TO APP");
                sendResponse({ spanish: "", english: "", context: "You haven't gathered any vocabulary yet! Select words in your browser to add them to your vocabulary.", hier: 0, timesViewed: 0, id: -1 });

            }

        });


    });
```

**App Script Snippet**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(vocabBrowserExtensionId, { action: "send_db" },
    function (response) {

        console.log("REPLY RECEIVED!");
        console.log(response.data);

        //Save db in app storage
        chrome.storage.local.get(dbName, function (storage) {

            storage[dbName] = response.data;

            chrome.storage.local.set(storage, function () {

                console.log("Card database saved!");
                callback.call(this);

            });

        });

    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To send a response from asynchronously executed code you need `return true` from the onMessageExternal listener e.g. [Chrome Extension Message passing: response not sent](//stackoverflow.com/a/20077854)

Comment: @wOxxOm My apologies, but I'm still a little unsure of where exactly this return true statement goes in my code specifically. Thanks!

Comment: Before the implicit return from the listener. You can see an example in the [reverted revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20077854/2) of the answer I've linked above. I wonder why the author of that answer reverted my edit. I didn't ask because I presumed he's not a nice fella lol.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! I tried putting "return true;" after the statement "sendResponse({ data: storage[lwsDatabaseName] });" and its corresponding call in the else statement. It's still not working... ideas?

Comment: Oh great! Yes that works! Thanks!